# Copying and pasting in Word and Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, microsoft-word-2003

I recently started having problem with pasting tables between Word documents and from Excel to Word. For some reasons it pastes table without frame, just disorganized text. It is very annoying because I never had this problem before. I tried options and ticked various things but it did not change anything. Please help. Can you write step by step what I should do?

Comment: What version of Excel & Word?

Comment: @uSlackr OP tagged the version I think.

Answer (score 1):

When you  paste the table, you should see this option:

[image: Paste options]

When you click it, you'll see option on how to handle the pasted table.  Try some of those options out.